# Integrate $2\pi \int{ax^2 \sqrt{1 + 4a^2 x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Does anyone knows a useful substitution for solving this integral?

$$I = 2\pi  \int{ax^2 \sqrt{1 + 4a^2 x^2}}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Make the substitution $2ax = \sinh(u)$ or $2ax = \tan(\theta)$.